# Upon running "python manage.py startapp blog" shows the following error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, migration, database-migration

I'm learning from djangogirls tutorials and when inside myenv(virtual environment) I'm running the `python manage.py startapp blog` it shows me the following error and can not run anything at all

error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\Users\Divyesh\djangogirls\myenv\lib\site-packages\django    \core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\Users\Divyesh\djangogirls\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "c:\Users\Divyesh\djangogirls\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "c:\Users\Divyesh\djangogirls\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "c:\Users\Divyesh\djangogirls\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in     _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in     _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Divyesh\djangogirls\dpblog\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from utils import timezone
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Also after that while running 
    python manage.py makemigrations blog

it shows almost identical error
I don't know how to tackle this please help. Learning Django for the first time.

Comment: try `django.utils`

Comment: Is your project already created?

Comment: No it is in process of creating it. I've just created the models.py file for now

Comment: I have solved it I guess, though its something alternate and I'm not understanding the root of this.

I've delted all the things that I've created earlier 
I've done everything again but....

this time I've installed django 1.11.0 instead of 'django 2.0'

'cause AFAI came to know that there are some incompatibility with sqlite3 and django2.0 that the errors were popping up

it all worked fine now as I've installed django~=1.11.0

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience using timezone, and based on the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/), you should be using:

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

instead of `from utils import timezone`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Even after writing django.utils it is showing me almost identical error. And there is some problem with __init.py__ in the import_models ,
    
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I don't know if you are supposed to do this but I went to the file manage.py on line 14 and commented out `from exc`.

so my line 14 on manage.py looks like this:

```
        )  # from exc
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and also got the solution now.
The error comes because you haven't got the Django script activated yet.

Open cmd in your django tutorial folder and then type: `Scripts\activate`.
e.g. `E:\django tutorial\blogcourse>Scripts\activate`

Once you have done this then on the command line it will look like this:
`(blogcourse) E:\django tutorial\blogcourse\src>`

Then you can type `python manage.py startapp personel`
eg:
`(blogcourse) E:\django tutorial\blogcourse\src>python manage.py startapp personel`

And you are done :)

[this is how it is done on my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXuyh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. Open settings.py file
2. Delete 'utils' and blog (if there) under INSTALL_APPS
3. `INSTALLED_APPS=['django.contrib.admin','django.contrib.auth','django.contrib.contenttypes','django.contrib.sessions','django.contrib.messages','django.contrib.staticfiles','blog','utils']`
4. Save the file and try running
   python manage.py startapp blog

This solution worked for me.